# Codeigniter URL config

Tags: nginx, codeigniter-3, php-7, linux-mint

I would like to adjust the url of my site which is done using Codeigniter to get the following format:

> site.com/controller/method

but when I try to do this I see the following screen on my site:

[image]

I'm using:

- Codeigniter 3.1.4
- Nginx 1.10.0
- PHP 7.0.19-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+2
- OS: Linux Mint 18.1 Serena

Comment: Has to be done through htaccess. The install should have a sample file specifically for this. If not, it's in the manual. Not posting as answer, because that's a pain from my phone.

Comment: @Joe `.htaccess` is used by the Apache web server. The questioner is using `nginx` which requires changes to the server configuration file.

Comment: Valid point. Didn't notice. My bad.

Comment: @RichardSmith Can you tell me how this configuration will go?

Comment: Your question is too broad to give a definitive answer - but [this recipe](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/) may be useful.